# Check status of samba4 in debian

Tags: debian, samba, samba4

In samba3, I can use command `/etc/init.d/samba status` to check status of samba service. But in samba4, that command does not exist. So I want to ask how to check status of samba4?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I run Samba in Debian

Comment: Works for me.. Could you show the output of `/etc/init.d/samba status`?

Comment: When I install samba4 in debian (from source code), the file /etc/init.d/samba does not exist

Comment: What are you referring to with "When I install samba4 in debian (from source code)"? Why aren't you using `apt-get install samba`?

Comment: If you do it manually, maybe it's up to you to put the files into the right place..

Comment: I must install samba4 on Debian6, so I cannot find out any source list for Samba4. Thanks for your help

Comment: So...check where the init file is located, and copy it to the right place?

Comment: Besides: To make it easier for people to help you, put as much information as possible into your question: Your OS, the version, how you installed samba (in this case), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will do that in the next time